# Twitter search with source parameter from oAuth application

Tags: search, twitter, oauth

Would anyone happen to know how you would run a Twitter search query based on a tweet coming from an oAuth Twitter application (source)?

For example, I want to be able to pull tweets that were posted from my Twitter application and be able to find it using the 'source' operator.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean search via Twitter API, something like:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=landing+source:tweetie
```

Comment: That's exactly what I mean, but how would you search updates made through an oAuth application or obtain a source parameter in the first place?

Comment: Seems, I still don't understand where the problem is:
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=source:bitly+twittertim.es
works fine for me. "bitly" here is name of the oAuth application and it's first placed.

Comment: I'm not talking about other applications here, I'm talking about how you would reference the source from updates coming from your own oAuth application?

I have tried to use the name of my application for the source with no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ok. Anyway, what does API return? Do you have an example of query and public tweet to search for?